# Django get URL from address bar

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, web

I am a begginer with django and I am stuck in getting this to work, practically what I want is that the user types in the address bar http://website.com/example and then in Django I want to make a dynamic view where it checks the address and then redirects user to the correct page otherwise gives an error.

this is what I was trying but it might not be working..

```py
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("<str:name>", views.example, name="example") ]
```

and then in the `views.py` I want the following:

```py
def example(request, name):
    return render(request, "website/<name> here i want for it to insert what the user typed in the address bar", {
        "name": util.get_entry(name)  <-- this is a function which checks if there is that name in the database otherwise will return an error.
    })
```

Hope I was clear with the question and thank you for the help :)

Comment: I believe you should switch the paths: ```urlpatterns = [path("<str:name>/", views.example, name="example") ],
path("", views.index, name="index"),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do here but I think you are trying to pass in a string as a parameter. In which case, you would do something like:

```
def example(request, name):
    #perform some logic with the name parameter like querying the database
    # results = Post.objects.filter(body__contains=name)

    return render(request, "blog/post.html", {"results": results})
```

You can then access 'results' in the specified template: 'blog/post.html'.
I hope this helps!